# Json Dataset Errors: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined & Cannot set property '_node' of null

Tags: javascript, json, dataset

I'm venturing into very uncharted territory (for me) and I would appreciate some input. I've been through S/O but any references to these errors are for what appear to be different scenarios.

In essence, I have a pretty standard mySQL query that creates an associative array of approximately 70 child arrays with 7 items within each array. I then use 'json_encode' to make it ready for use in a grid. A print_r lists everything correctly with all data intact (see below).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [c_ksa] => 1
            [urgency] => 3
            [position_id] => 1000115
            [position_root] => Maintenance C&M
            [position_area] => Construction West
            [positionmgr_uid] => dale.jones@gmail.com
            [last_name] => Jones
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [c_ksa] => 1
            [urgency] => 1
            [position_id] => 1000172
            [position_root] => Creative C&M
            [position_area] => Design/Build
            [positionmgr_uid] => anita.smith@gmail.com
            [last_name] => Smith
        )
```

However, in Dev Tools I'm getting the two errors:

```
Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined
```

and

```
Cannot set property '_node' of null
```

I have no idea where to start looking. Are these data type errors? Is this 'object' related? I don't have much experience in this area - but I'm willing to learn if someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like the code you provided is not valid JavaScript code.

Comment: @ Nguyễn Việt Đức . In what way is it not valid? With "undefined" and "null" in the error strings, I would assume that this is referring to data in some way but the JSON output looks good (at least to my eye). Any thoughts on where to start looking? Thank you.

Comment: Like this part: [position_root] => Maintenance C&M. Is it JS here or just some pseudocode?

Comment: [position_root] is a column in mySQL DB. The array is from the mySQL query so not pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much more exploring, I found the problem. In my application I have a table containing a column listing the managers in an org who sponsor an employee into a specific program. Because a manager can sponsor more than one employee, there will be repeats (duplicates) in this column. I had set the 'id' in my SQL query ("AS id") to that column so when I tried to use the resulting array while referencing the 'id' there were conflicts due to the duplicates. When this was fixed, all errors were resolved. Lesson learned ...